# Can I remove a column if it's part of a primary key?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I need to remove blank columns or columns ending in "ID" but I'm getting an error stating Cannot remove this column, because it's part of the primary key. Here is my code, any help is much appreciated.

```
' Remove blank columns or columns ending in "ID"
          If objColumn.ColumnName = "" OrElse (objColumn.ColumnName.Length > 1 AndAlso objColumn.ColumnName.Right(2) = "ID") Then
                objColumnsToDelete.Add(objColumn)
            End If
        Next

        For Each objDelCol As System.Data.DataColumn In objColumnsToDelete
            dtExport.Columns.Remove(objDelCol)
        Next
```

Comment: Instead of removing columns from DataTable, create an object from DataTable with only columns you need for further working with data.

Comment: The columns aren't static unfortunately since depending on the user's location change them.

Comment: Why are you removing them in the first place? If you don't want certain data at all then why retrieve it at all? If you have all the data but don't want to display it then don't display it, but leave it in the `DataTable`. It just seems like you might be trying to solve the wrong problem. I think that a FULL and CLEAR explanation is in order, which is what you should provide in the first place.